# Installing Tensorflow to conda virtual env

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv, conda

I've compiled tensorflow from source. I've wheel file (`/tmp/tensorflow_pkg//tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl`). What I want to do is to install this wheel file to specific conda virtual environment.
What I've tried so far
1. [Installing using pip](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) After activating the virtual env.
 But this installs the package for all envs.
2. Installing with the following command

```
conda install -n env_name /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
```

But I get the following error.

```
 Fetching package metadata ...........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

How could I install wheel package to conda environment.

Comment: What do you mean "This installs the package for all envs"? How can you tell that pip has done that? Note that the second method is expected to fail because conda cannot install wheels

Comment: Say I don't have package `x` installed in my machine. if i install it using pip after activating lets say env `y`, even after deactivating the env i can import package `x`.

Comment: What is the output of `which pip` after you've activated the environment?

Comment: path/to/env/bin/pip

Comment: Have you set your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Are you using the `--user` option to pip? There is no reason for something installed with pip from a specific environment to be imported everywhere, so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: This might give you some insights, I've installed the tensorflow wheel with pip using command "pip install  path/to/wheel/file . when I imported tensorflow and here is output of tensorflow.__path__
/path/to/andaconda2/lib/python2.7/sitepackes/tensorflow

Comment: So what is the problem? It seems like it works?